# Contents of Image folder after building in Yocto

Tags: image, yocto, beagleboneblack

I tried to build an image with default machine name "beaglebone-yocto". On the folder ../images
there are multiple dtb, u-boot, mlo, like on the image attached.
Does anyone one, what is difference between MLO and MLO-beaglebone-yocto or 
am335x-boneblack-beaglebone-yocto.dtb and am335x-boneblack.dtb?
Thank you
Best regards.
[image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXeiN.png)

Comment: A 'ls -l' command in that directory will explains a lot...

Comment: I would recommend looking into the recipies which produce those output.